# Azure Update Management - Automated VMs onboarding

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to automate VMs onboarding process for Azure Update Management. I am wondering if it possible, I didnt find solution which I can use to full onboard VM to Update Management, from A-Z. I mean I need MMA agent installation (i have script prepared, for installing mma vm extension with workspace ID and Key). Problem is that thare I didn't find a way to perform rest of the steps. Did anyone try to do this, I know that Ms give the runbook form this but I am not sure if its working as expected, link here --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/enable-from-runbook

Comment: Hello, Is this an Azure VM or Hybrid VM?

Comment: Hi, all machines in my env are azure cloud VMs.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can automate it by configuring UM to automatically enable for all existing and future VMs using this method - [Enable Machine in the workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/enable-from-automation-account#enable-machines-in-the-workspace)

But keep in mind that using this method doesn't allow you to have the control an enterprise customer would want.

We don't have an out of the box method to configure from the VM, onboarding it to UM in an automated manner. Based on how it is designed, the only way out of the box is from the portal, or runbook as described in docs.

Programatically to work around this (and I'm thinking out loud here) you could update the saved search query - **MicrosoftDefaultComputerGroup** in the workspace with the UUID of the VM and that would automate onboarding it to the feature.  I don't have a working example to share but I think the approach is sound and can be included in the workflow to onboard it.

Comment: I was thinking about updating default computer Group. Reg. Runbook for onbording VMs, suggested by MS, dud you test this method?